# How to reject the attributes in fastjson_api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastjsonapi

I'm started using fastjson_api, I have implemented attribute-based control in my project how do reject the attributes when I'm returning the JSON data.
For Example:-
I have a customer table where it has customer name, email, phone, address
For some roles, I may give access to phone number and for some, I'll not give them access
`not_allowed_attributes = ["phone"]`

```
class CustomerSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :name, :email, :phone  
  attribute :phone do |object|
    unless not_allowed_attributes.include?"phone"
      object.phone
    end
  end
end
```

But It is not a dynamic way of implementing, so whenever there is changed in not_allowed_attributes it should dynamically filter out the attributes from the JSON response.
For role1 not_allowed_attributes = ["email","phone"]
for role2 not_allowed_attributes = ["phone"]

not_allowed_attributes I'll send it in params for the serializer and there is it possible to remove the attributes based on their role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [conditional attributes](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#conditional-attributes) of FastJSONAPI, by passing in a Proc. I'm not exactly clear how your code implements roles, but let's assume you have an `admin` role and you want to display the phone when the user is an admin. The code below should work for that use case:

```
class CustomerSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :name, :email, :phone  
  attribute :phone, if: Proc.new { |record| record.admin? }
end
```

Comment: let say not_allowed_attributes has name and email for other roles again I need to define a block to that attribute, can it be implemented in such a way that it should check and it should attach the attribute otherwise it should not.

Comment: Can you show what not_allowed_attributes looks like?

Comment: Hi nwocha, thanks for the response I have edit the questions, actucally for role1 not_allowed_attributes = ["phone"] and for role2 not_allowed_attributes = ["email"] is it possible to reject attributes in serializer class.